# LIKE character length limitation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

The background to this question [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870222/sql-query-to-find-most-effective-data).

The following part of my stored procedure does not work. Is there a character length limitation for the `LIKE` clause? `t1.ProductList` sometimes can be up to 1000 characters in length:

```
DELETE t1 FROM #tmptable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #tmptable2_ t2
              WHERE t1.DealerId != t2.DealerId
              AND t2.ProductList LIKE '%' + t1.ProductList + '%'
              AND t2.numberOfVibs > t1.numberOfVibs);
```

Sample data for a single row of the `ProductList` column:

<sub>B1ZMA25706,B1ZMI09502,B1ZMI12910,B1ZMI18602,BB001TBL26,BBHMOVE4,BE09501FBL,BGS52200,BKS3003,BM2,BO11001EBO,BPGTB1200,BPGTC172HP,BPGTX663,BPIVMS6502,BPIVOD1022,BPVA475,BPVB1000,BPVB800,BPVC652,BPVPW1500,BPVW1000,BPVX652,BPVX662,BREMEN78,BSA2602,BSD2880,BSG62082,BSG71800,BSG81623,BSG82422,BSG82480,BSGL32015,CAB150,CAB21,CD1401B,CD21001WAL,CD21004WAL,CD2105WHI,CD2108WAL,CD5601S,CDBSE7300A,CEPM8CAPPU</sub>

Comment: What do you mean by 'does not work'?  Do you get an error, no results without error or what else?  Can you identify a row where it works and another one where not?

Comment: I dont get error but if i delete that part result is same.

Comment: Could you show some sample data?

Comment: @dezso Added content.

Comment: Could you reformat it into tabular format?  It would be interesting to see ProductList from t1 and t2.  Apropos, how do you populate those two tables?  What is their structure?

Comment: to fit the conditions t2 would have to have a productlist with at least the exact same "text" as t1. Similar in order, spacing, content ...

Comment: @bummi Why do you think so?

Comment: Actual problem is there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870222/sql-query-to-find-most-effective-data

Comment: @ dezso http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/2586, -- commented select will give 1, last select will give 0

Comment: @bummi OK, I think I got your point.  The wording was not really easy to comprehend for me.

Comment: Is the value in t1.ProductList a comma separated list of values, or is it a normal table with one value per row?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *Is there any character length limitation for LIKE clause?*

Yes. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) for `LIKE`:

> *pattern*
>
> > Is the specific string of characters to search for in match_expression, and can include the following valid wildcard characters. *pattern* can be a maximum of **8,000 bytes**.

In your case the limit is **4,000 characters** because the `FOR XML PATH` expression returns a **Unicode** string (two bytes per character). If you check the `ProductList` column of your temporary table, you will see the data type is `nvarchar(max)`:

```
EXECUTE tempdb.sys.sp_help
    @objname = N'#tmptable';
```

[image: sp_help output]

Depending on your data, you may be able to use single-byte `ANSI` characters instead, giving you up to **7,998 characters** for the concatenated string of `ProductCodes`:

```
CREATE TABLE #SellerProducts
(
    SellerID        integer PRIMARY KEY,
    ProductList     varchar(7998) NOT NULL,
    ProductCount    bigint NOT NULL
);

INSERT #SellerProducts
(
    SellerID, 
    ProductList, 
    ProductCount
)
SELECT
    s.SellerId,
    STUFF
    (
        (
        SELECT
            ',' + ProductCode 
        FROM Stocks
        WHERE
            s.SellerId = Stocks.SellerId
        ORDER BY
            ProductCode
        FOR XML 
            PATH('')
        )
        , 1, 1, ''
    ),
    COUNT_BIG(*)
FROM dbo.Stocks AS s
WHERE
    s.ProductCode IN ('30A','20A','42B')
    AND s.StockData > 0
GROUP BY
    s.SellerId;
```

The code above is *deliberately* designed to throw the following error if `ProductList` contains more than 7,998 characters:

[image: error message]

You do **not** need to create a second copy of the temporary table to do the `DELETE`:

```
DELETE t1 
FROM #SellerProducts AS t1
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM #SellerProducts AS t2
    WHERE
        t2.SellerId <> t1.SellerId
        AND t2.ProductList LIKE '%' + t1.ProductList + '%'
        AND t2.ProductCount > t1.ProductCount
);
```

The character limit for the `ProductList` column is 7,998 characters to allow two for the `%` characters added before the `LIKE` is performed - giving a total of 8,000 characters, the maximum allowed for the `LIKE` *pattern* string.